# Faust: "Namen sind Schall und Rauch", Nomina sunt

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

From a quick search this German aphorism appears to be from (at least *in*) Goethe's Faust.

The Latin parallel that comes to mind is *Nomen est Omen*. With that in mind, I often find myself reaching for a Latin rendition of the former, as well. **Is there an unambiguous or at least sufficiently common translation?**

---

Rational:
*It's not easy to translate the phrase in both dimensions of felicity and fidelity--more so if going through English, which I am trying to avoid here. The best hope would be that Goethe hadn't made it up completely, so that a reasonable reconstruction could be attempted, if the etymological falacy would not be too painful.*

*It's difficult to sum up the significance of* Schall *here. That would better be left for German.SE. The meaning of the phrase in whole in current speech might be a matter of debate, and literature criticism, too, that's out of the question. FWIW I'd say both* Rauch *and* Schall *imply a sense of the temporary, but painting with a however broad stroke I'm inclined to remind you that almost anything is temporary. Consequently, many different connotations can be found.*

Feel free to use your own brush and be as colorful as you like. Don't loose time; first to answer receives the award.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up the brush for a first sketch.

**Sunt nomina verba vana volatiliaque.**

An immediate  association I had when reading the question was with the first words spoken by Jorge of Burgos in Umberto Eco's "The Name of the Rose": **Verba vana aut risui apta non loqui**. They come from the [Regula Benedicti](https://ora-et-labora.net/RSB_itlat.html), capitula IV - *Quae sunt instrumenta bonorum operum*, number 53.

This [site](https://germanblogs.de/namen-sind-schall-und-rauch) has the following:

"Man betont mit dem Zitat (*Name ist Schall und Rauch*), dass ein Name allein noch nichts über eine Person oder Sache aussagt, dass Namen vergänglich sind." (The phrase is used to stress that a mere name does not say anything about a person or an object, that names are transitory [translation mine]).

A logical follow-up association is the one between Rauch (smoke) and volatility. **Sunt** is not mandatory: if you leave it out, you can abbreviate to NVVV.

And about **Nomen est omen** (which I believe does not carry the aspect of temporariness):

According to this page in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nomen_est_omen), "[t]he origin of this saying is attributed to the Roman playwright Plautus. In his play “Persa” the slave Toxilus lures his owner, Dordalus, to buy an expensive slave-girl named Lucris (“profits”), saying, “Nōmen atque ōmen quantīvīs iam est pretī” (“The name and the omen are worth any price”)."

Retouches, anyone?